# What is the nomenclature for the relationship of a class to its associated metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminology, metaclass

What do we call the relationship of a class towards its associated metaclass?

I'd like to fill the blank in the following two lines:

- Class A is the metaclass of class B.
- Class B is the ________ of class A.

In the documentation of the class, I am documenting a metaclass I am currently writing. I find my self typing "the class associated to this metaclass" very often in the python docstrings. Is there a single word which I can use to denote this kind of relationship in a more concise manner?

Condensed example in which I'd like to use a more concise nomenclature:

```py
def __init__(mcl, what, bases=None, dict=None):
  """
  Raises an exception if >> the class associated to this metaclass << 
  contains a valid set of configuration decorators.
  ...
  """
```

Comment: The term appears to be "classes derived from" or "classes created from": https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta

Comment: "derived from" is not accurate - it implies a relation of inheritance and superclasses. The term is not used in the documentation you linked to as well - the verb "derive" there is used to explain either normal inheritance from ABCs or for metaclasses that should inherit from ABCMeta. "created from" could be ok - but IMO (and I might be mistaken by thinking in "from" as I would in my native language)  "created with" would be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official nomenclature for that. The only way to go is the full formal way: "the class B for which A is the metaclass" or equivalent.

Technically one could just say that "class B" is an "instance of "class A" - but no other context given it would be very hard for anyone to figure out you are talking about class-metaclass relationship.

For the specific case you mention, though, it would work, I think - you could replace ">> the class associated to this metaclass << " for ">> the class which is an instance of this metaclass << "

Comment: I would argue there is nothing special about the class-metaclass relationship beyond  it being an instance-of relation. It think your last sentence is really the important part of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The term "metaclass" itself already captures much of the relationship you are looking. A metaclass isn't really a special thing; it's just another type. The "magic" is that *instances* of this type also happen to be types. (What is a type? It's just a class which provides methods for objects.)

If anything, *classes* are the special things. You could imagine that metametaclasses exist: types whose instances are metaclasses, whose instances are classes. You could build up an infinite hierarchy of such metameta...classes. (In practice, this doesn't exist in Python. The root metaclass `type` has itself as its own metaclass, not some other higher-order metametaclass.) A class, then, is unique as the only sort of type whose instances cannot also serve as types.

The relationship you are looking for is just "class B is an instance of (meta)class A".

(Nothing I say here should be taken as a contradiction of [jsbueno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621709/1126841); I think it's just a different perspective.)

Comment: "In practice, this doesn't exist in Python" - to the contrary, as type is its own metaclass, the "infinite hierarchy" _exists_ and is  _implemented_. It took me several years until I even could figure out an example in which a second order metaclass would be useful - (and then once I even used it in real code: I wanted some special "dunder" methods to work on a metaclass). But indeed, beyond second orderm although existing in practice, I think there is no conceivable use for them.

Comment: As for your answer, yours differ from mine where I open saying "there is no term for that [inverse relation of metaclass]" - of course, not in the same sense that the term "metaclass" exists. The inverse relationship is of "instances [of the metaclass]", but then one could just say that "[the metalclass] is the class[/type] of [the class]", with no need for the term "metaclass" itself.

Comment: That's kind of a degenerate hierarchy, but I see your point.

Comment: I agree; I think the term metaclass is only necessary to help explain that types aren't really any different from other objects, something that's not obvious coming from other languages.

Comment: I like to think of the type-kind-sort hierarchy in Haskell as a good analogy (and the actual infinite hierarchy in languages like Idris), though it's not perfect with the subtle differences between OOP class instantiation and the use of type/data constructors in functional languages.